# After 'outer join left ' how to select only 2 data from column associated with the same 'common id' when there's more than 2..?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, outer-join

i have a posts table with columns :

```
id | content
```

and a comments table with columns:

```
id | content | post_id
```

i used outer left join :

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.content,comments.content AS comment_content
FROM posts LEFT JOIN
     comments
     ON comments.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY posts.id
```

when i do this i get the Resultset :

[image]

as u can see in the below image that i have higlighted from above  resultset :
a post has 3 comment associated with it ..(here id and content are of posts)

[image]

how do i get only 2 comment associated with a single post id instead of all the comments associated with the post id.(in this case all the comments associated with post_id=5 are 3 comments)

Comment: Enumerate then select only rows where the number is 1 or 2. You must have some sorting criteria (for example, some `comment_created_at` datetime column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.content, c.content AS comment_content
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.post_id ORDER BY c.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM comments c
     ) c
     ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.seqnum <= 2
ORDER BY p.id;
```

Note:  The above returns the two comments with the highest `id`s -- which are presumably the most recent comments.  If you want two random comments, use `rand()` instead.

Comment: this works the best but the 'FROM posts ' should be  'FROM posts p' since alias p is used for posts.

Comment: nah dude , i should be thanking u , the only reason i didnt was its discouraged by the site.THANK YOU man.